# Asp.net application with multiple databases

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an `asp.net` application ,, currently i'm using `Sql Server 2008` as backend.
However i have been asked to develop one application with multiple databases (`oracle,sql server,mysql` etc). Is it possible to achieve this.Is it a feasible solution.What may be the possible disadvantages associated with it.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean one application that uses all these different databases *at the same time*, or one application that be installed to use *either* SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc

Comment: @PhilPursglove ,,, the database could use any one of above mentioned database ,, i mean it should be flexible to be compatible with any one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's feasible. You'll need a connection string for each database type (and catalog) in your web.config and you may need to install different drivers on your server (like the ODBC driver).

The only disadvantage I can think of off the top of my head is you won't be able to easily join tables between databases. If you ever have to do that, you'll need to select from the individual database tables and either:

1. loop through the tables in your code-behind and manually process the data like a join would.
2. or insert the selected tables into a temporary table on one of the databases and then use that server to do the join .

Answer (score 1):

This should be feasible, but it might not be easy.

You'll need a Data Access Layer that insulates you from the details of each database, as each database will have *slightly* different syntax in it's language, meaning you (probably) won't be able to write one query that'll work across them all. You haven't said what the domain of your system is, but in, let's say, a bookshop your DAL would have methods like `GetBooks`, `GetBook`, `GetCustomer` etc.

Underneath your DAL you'll probably then have a set of different .NET assemblies, each of which knows how to run your queries against one database (SQL Server, Oracle etc). When one of the methods in your DAL is called, your DAL passes that onto the appropriate assembly to actually make the call and return the results to your application back through the DAL. Your DAL will need to be able to create instances of the classes in the assemblies, there's a few different ways to do this but I would suggest MEF as being probably the most straightforward.

Disadvantages:

1. Because you need to be generic, it's unlikely you'll be able to use
   a particular feature of any one database
2. It'll take longer because for each feature you develop, you need to write the code in the DAL for it, and then write the code for each separate database assembly, plus any SQL coding in the database itself, *and* then test it for each database.

Comment: +1 @Freebird I've tended to implement the Repository pattern in such circumstances using a method not dissimilar to this -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx.  Here the inversion of control allows you to define the interface of the repository in the BL and then leave it to the Datalayer and RespositoryFactory to handle the rest.  HTH

Comment: @PhilPursglove ,,, thanks a lot ,,, m doing more research on the topic ,,, when i plan to go for it ,, may ill contact you again for some additional guidance ,  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to solve this problem would be to use the SQL Server as the layer that ties together the different databases.  SQL Server 2005 and later have a feature called [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  This will let you link to other database.

This approach will allow you to model you datalayer as if it was one database and let SQL Server abstract the complexities of the multiple databases.

You can also look at the SQL Server feature called [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).  This will allow you to query other databases with out setting up the linked servers.

Comment: ,,, thank you so much ,,, ill have to get back to you after my research on this when i am about go for it.thanks